# Could not load file or assembly System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, remoting

The application i am developing is a simple remote chat application.

I am experiencing this exception when i try to run my application. I really do not understand when it talks about loading file or assembly.

> "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Client, Version=1.0.0.0"

```
try
{
   gt = (Greeting)Activator.GetObject(typeof(Greeting), "tcp://Localhost:7189/Greeting");
   handler = new MessageHandler(OnReceive);
   gt.Sender += handler;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   textBox2.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

This exception is Thrown at this line

```
gt.Sender += handler;
```

Below is my Greetings class.

```
[Serializable]
public delegate void MessageHandler(string mymsg);
public class Greeting:MarshalByRefObject
{
    public event MessageHandler Sender;

    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Greeting()
    {
    }

    public void postGreeting(string msg)
    {
        if (Sender != null)
        {
            Sender(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `MessageHandler` in the Client assembly? Has this assembly been loaded into the BIN/GAC? .NET doesn't load referenced assemblies until they are first called so this may be the source of your problem.

Comment: The exception has occurred inside the Greeting class. You will have to debug/explore that object. Appears that a method in it might be expecting a logfile or something at a path which is not available on your machine.

Comment: @FrazellThomas I am new to Remoting, i do not know how to check if the assembly have been loaded into the BIN/GAC. Perhaps you can suggest ways of loading this assembly into the BIN/GAC.

Comment: @PrahladYeri i kind of get what you are saying but not clearly. I we can will post my Greetings class so look at it.

Comment: I will certainly look at the Greetings class, but the best way to find out is to debug this. Can't you add the solution containing Greetings class to yours, and debug it in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the handler is created within your Client assembly? A reference to the handler is passed to your server assembly when you subscribe to the Greetings.Sender event. As part of the deserialization on the server side it must resolve the handler type. As it lives within the Client assembly this must be accessible to the server assembly.

Build all of your assemblies into a single shared debug or release folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use microsoft sysinternals process monitor, confiure the tool to watch all file access operations of your application, then you can see what assembly your process is trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

the idea of using microsoft sysinternals process monitor worked perfectly for me. i was able to see that it was looking for one of the dependencies in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you experience `Could not load file or assembly` use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) (on disk called `fuslogvw.exe` and availbale from the .NET SDK) to find out exactly what your process is actually probing, either in the GAC or your application folder.

A typical logentry will hold info similar to this:

```
LOG: Processing DEVPATH.
LOG: DEVPATH is not set. Falling through to regular bind.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Post-policy reference: graphicfailtest.resources, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft.NET/FrameworkSDK/Samples/Tutorials/resourcesandlocalization/graphic/cs/en-US/graphicfailtest.resources.DLL.
```

and you can then verify that it loads assemblies from a location you expect, inclusing if it is the correct version.

[Probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx) from the msdn docs.